# Why does arduino uses macros for certain 'functions' like min(), max(), constrain()?

Tags: c++, arduino, macros

Though I am a fan of macros in general, I am not getting why the Arduino makers chose to use macros instead of actual functions for some of their arithmatic "functions". To name a few examples:

```
min()
max()
constrain()
```

Their website informs one not to call functions from within these "functions" or to use pre/postfix inside the brackets() because they are actually macros.

Considering the arduino language is actually C++, they could have easily used (inline) functions instead and prevent any user from falling in one of the well known macro pitfalls.

People usually do things for reasons. And so far I have not found these reasons. So my qeustion: why did the Arduino makers chose to use macro's instead of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino is built based on much older codes and libraries such as [AVR-libc](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/avr-libc/) where macros are used extensively way before Arduino even existed.

In modern programming, macros are not recommended (versus inline functions) as it does not do type checking, does not check compile errors and if not craft carefully could lead to some side-effects.

Comment: Thanks, do you also know why they never bothered to transform these macros into functions? It seems to me like a ~15 minute job

Comment: @bask185: This has often been put up as an issue on Github, but they never did it, as far as I know. Maybe they are afraid it will break existing code somehow; there is many a quaint and curious construction being carried over from version to version for that reason.

Comment: @bask185, Well, the more you know about Arduino, the more you will find that there are many things that can be done better. Personally, I feel that arduino.cc is quite lay back, for example, they never bother to [set the fuse correctly](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/issues/10) to free up 1.5k flash memory on arduino nano when they switch to optiboot bootloader; they never bother to add an [build option](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/01/do-you-know-arduino-sprintf-and-floating-point/) (this blog was written by me) to allow user to have floating point support, etc.

Comment: I stopped using the IDE and switched to CLI some time ago. The text editor of the IDE is very sub-standard. I have had issues with their file system as well. I think that the relative include paths and the forced used of the src folder also fall in the category, 'could have been done better' or atleast different